# How to multiply subset of matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a stupid question: how can I multiply a section of a matrix by a factor?

```
my_matrix[, gender == "male"] = 6 # works
my_matrix[, gender == "male"] = my_matrix[, gender == "male"] * 6 # results in problems downstream
```

What I want to do is to take every value on which the filter matches * 6. I guess that's not what's happening.

Comment: What  the expected result would look like?

Answer (score 2):

The `gender == "male"` would be row index instead of column index

```
my_matrix[gender == "male", ] <- my_matrix[gender == "male", ] * 6
```

Also, assuming that `my_matrix` would be also numeric columns and `gender` is a `vector` with length equal to the number of rows of 'my_matrix'